# Regex for pipe separated [[:alnum:]]* list

Tags: bash, regular-expression

what is the reliable regex for pipe-separated `[[:alnum:]]*` strings set on a variable? the regex should also cover case when variable is unset.

accepted:

```
var="abc123|A1B2C3|sDsdSS|"
var="abc123|A1B2C3"
var="abc123"
var=""
```

and probably also some superfluous pipes are ok (supported in my `grep`):

```
var="|||r44fDs||fe4REee|||"
```

I am using this "var" list later in my script to exclude given lines from the input file:

```
grep -vE "^(${var}) " input > input.filtered
```

Mine regex returns also space-separated and special characters which are not ok for me:

```
$ echo -e "sfsfds|sfsf|sfdsf|||\ns@ds|fsfsf|fssfsdf|sfsdfdfs\nsdfsdfsfs\nafafafs sdfsfd dfsfsfs\n"|grep -E '([[:alnum:]]*\|*)*'
sfsfds|sfsf|sfdsf|||
s@ds|fsfsf|fssfsdf|sfsdfdfs
sdfsdfsfs
afafafs sdfsfd dfsfsfs

$
```

Comment: So what is wrong with ones you have? Could you provide an actual input file and output needed? What is `input`? Is it a file or a sample string

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you explain more?

Comment: So you want to exclude lines containing pipes? mean to ignore the first line in the above input?

Comment: @Inian, no I want break script if var does not match regex requirements which I described

Answer (score 1):

**`grep`** solution:

Sample `input.txt`:

```
sfsfds|sfsf|sfdsf|||
s@ds|fsfsf|fssfsdf|sfsdfdfs
sdfsdfsfs
afafafs sdfsfd dfsfsfs
```

---

```
var='^[[:alnum:]]+[[:alnum:]\|]*$'
grep -E "$var" input.txt
```

The output:

```
sfsfds|sfsf|sfdsf|||
sdfsdfsfs
```

Comment: it is nearly correct, it does not pass when var="" (no exclude list) which I had mentioned in my question too.

Comment: @DonJ, you can't tell `grep` to exclude something with an empty string `""` given by a variable

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
grep -x '[[:alnum:]|]*'
```

That is, any sequence of 0 or more alnums or `|`. You don't need extended (`-E`) regexps here. That syntax is valid in both basic and extended regexps (and PCRE and most other regexps, the only thing that might not be supported in some would be that `[:alnum:]` POSIX character class).

The only thing missing from yours was the `-x` option to force the regexp to match on the line as a whole as opposed to finding matches within the line. The regexp nesting was overkill. You'd need it if you wanted the `|` delimited fields to be non-empty:

```
grep -xE '[[:alnum:]]+(\|[[:alnum:]]+)*'
```

Which can also be done with basic REs, though less legibly:

```
grep -x '[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\(|[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\)*'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var='^[[:alnum:]|]*$'
```

Comment: That also matches on `x\\\\\\\\\\\\x`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - oh, I thought the `|` needed to be escaped. I changed it on your word, thanks.